# Android Chat Application - Issue on Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello everybody i am following sample chat app from the link     ? and on -receive method is not being called.I want the List View, but there is any problem registering the receiver.My code is

```
public class UserListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "UserListActivity";
    TextView content;
    Button refreshButton;
    private Intent intent;
    MessageSender messageSender;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
        content.setText("Select user to chat:");
        refreshButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
        intent = new Intent(this, GCMNotificationIntentService.class);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, 
        newIntentFilter("com.javapapers.android.gcm.chat.userlist"));
        messageSender = new MessageSender();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get user list
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putString("ACTION", "USERLIST");
                messageSender.sendMessage(dataBundle, gcm);
            }
        });   
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + intent.getStringExtra("USERLIST"));
            updateUI(intent.getStringExtra("USERLIST"));
        }
    };

    private void updateUI(String userList) {
        //get userlist from the intents and update the list
        String[] userListArr = userList.split(":");    
        Log.d(TAG,"userListArr: "+userListArr.length+" 
        tostr"+userListArr.toString());
        //remove empty strings :-)
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s : userListArr) {
            if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        userListArr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userListArr);
        setListAdapter(adapter);   
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id){
            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;    
            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);   
            content.setText("User selected: " +itemValue);    
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ChatActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("TOUSER",itemValue);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }    

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_list, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            super.onDestroy(); 
        }
    }
}
```

And my manifestfile.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.mychat" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission. RECEIVE"      />
    <uses-permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ChatActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name="SignUpActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name="UserListActivity" ></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.mychat.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.mychat" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.example.mychat.GCMNotificationIntentService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: register receiver in onResume and unRegister in onPause

Comment: and from where you are sending Broadcast

Comment: Just confirm that you are rightly broadcasting the intent action "com.javapapers.android.gcm.chat.userlist"

Comment: hello rehman i am not sending broadcast can u please help where to send the broadcast

Comment: in onMessageReceive funciton where gcm server send message you will sendBroadcast in that funciton

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Add this line unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
    content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    content.setText("Select user to chat:");
    refreshButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    intent = new Intent(this, GCMNotificationIntentService.class);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.javapapers.android.gcm.chat.userlist"));
    messageSender = new MessageSender();
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get user list
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putString("ACTION", "USERLIST");
            messageSender.sendMessage(dataBundle, gcm);
        }
    });
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```